# Convert kth bit from last

Tags: haskell

Hi I am new in haskell.

Can any one tell me to convert Kth bit from last of given Integer in haskell.

For n = 37 and k = 3, the output should be
killKthBit(n, k) = 33.

37 = 100**1**01 ~> 100**0**01 = 33.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `Bits` typeclass in [`Data.Bits`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Bits.html). Integer has an instance for `Bits`, so you can:

```
clearBit 37 2 -- 2 because we are indexing from 0.
```

Comment: No it doesn't you must have mistyped (GHC Version 8.0.1).

Comment: Still strange. `clearBit 37 0` gives 36. I don't see how 36 would make sense for `clearBit 37 2`.

Comment: import Data.Bits 
    
killKthBit n k = clearBit n k-1

Comment: You forgot the parenthesis around `(k-1)` ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127994/discussion-between-aman-jaiswal-and-jpath).